# Could anyone explain to me why this is an element of this function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Consider the function $f:\Bbb N\to\wp(\Bbb N)$ defined as $f(n) = \emptyset$.

For the question "Find a set $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ s.t. $S\ne D$, but $f(n)\ne S\forall n\in\Bbb N$

how does set $\{137\}$ suffice for an $S$? I don't understand the original function f to begin with. Doesn't $\wp (\Bbb N)$ denote the power set of natural numbers?

Also, would any set containing natural numbers like $\{19\},\{100\}$ work?

Comment: What does $D$ represent?

Comment: You need $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ to satisfy the immediate requirement. And you need $S\ne\emptyset$ to satisfy $S\ne f(42)$. Incidentally, thius already guarantees that $f(n)=\emptyset\ne S$ for all $n$. -- After explanation of $D$ in a comment: As $f(x)=\emptyset$ and $x\ne\emptyset$ for all $x\in\Bbb N$, clearly $D=\Bbb N$; so that is the only other set to avoid.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone D = { x ∈ N | x ∉ f(x) } sorry for missing that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how does set {137} suffice the criteria tho?

Comment: The set $\{137\}$ is (a) a subset of $\Bbb N$ and (b) not empty (and (c) not all of $\Bbb N$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen oh so it can be any non-empty set that is a subset of ℕ BUT isn't ℕ itself?

Comment: [Edit] information into your question.

Comment: Use MathJax, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D = \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x \notin f(x) \}=\{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x \notin \emptyset \}=\mathbb{N}.$

You need to find $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $S\ne D=\mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.\ f(n) = \emptyset\ne S.$

So $S$ must be a non empty proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Pick one.

Comment: Hi, I have a follow-up question. If the f : N → ℘(N) was defined as f(n) = { m ∈ N | m ≥ n }, will {137} work again also for S? If so, how?

Comment: Is $D$ the same as before?

Comment: no  is ∅ now, which I'm also curious about.

Comment: Ok, so you need $S \ne \emptyset$ and $S \ne f(0)=\mathbb{N}$,  $S \ne f(1)=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$,  $S \ne f(2)=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}$, $S \ne f(3)=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1,2\}, \ldots$  (can you see the pattern?). So every non empty proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ not consisting of infinitely many consecutive elements does the work, in particular $\{137\}$.